# How can i get the mutual friend from facebook using facebook graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch the facebook mutual friend using facebook graph API but getting getting error only.

This is url that i am trying to hit 
http://graph.facebook.com/109557?fields=context.fields%28mutual_friends%29

Here is its Response :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#12) context field requires version v2.0 or higher",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 12
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to use at least API version 2.0 for this. Since you did not specify a version within your call, it will use the lowest one available for your app, and that seems to be v1 still in your case. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe said, you should try

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{user_id}?fields=context.fields%28mutual_friends%29
```

Comment: hi Tobi,
Thanks for you response but i try this already this did not work for me. I also use the  all version like v0.2 & v2.3 . I  test this on Facebook Graph API explorer all give me same error that i show above.

Comment: Works for me without any problem... https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dcontext.fields(mutual_friends)&